# Use React Hooks to fetch data from MySQL with Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have this problem and I hope that you'll be able to help me. So, I've created a React Hook to fetch data from my MySQL database. The code written for the hook is presented below:

```
const useMySQLToView = (table) => {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:4999/get"+table)
            setRows(result)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [table])

    return rows
}
```

Then I tried to get data using the hook on my component:

```
function ViewEmployees() {
    const {employees} = useMySQLToView('Employees')
    console.log(employees)
    return (
        <div>
            View employees
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is that this console.log(employees) returns undefined. Do you know why? How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: your employees state should update when data is available from the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `const {employees} = useMySQLToView('Employees')` with

`const employees = useMySQLToView('Employees')`

Since your hook is simply returning `rows` and not an object you can destructure